# Depth First Search (Adjacency Matrix) finding parent

Tags: c

How do I edit my code such that it also prints the parent of each vertex? Currently writing a **C program** to implement an algorithm based on Depth-First Search to test the connectivity of a given network.

Input:

- Adjacency matrix

Output:

- The sequence that vertices are being visited
- The vertices of each connected component of a given graph
- The parent of each vertex

```
#include<stdio.h>

void DFS(int);
int G[10][10],visited[10],V;    //V is no of vertices and graph is sorted in array G[10][10]
int component=0;

void main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter number of vertices:");

    scanf("%d",&V);

    //read the adjecency matrix
    printf("\nEnter adjecency matrix of the graph:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
       for(j=0;j<V;j++)
            scanf("%d",&G[i][j]);

    //visited is initialized to zero
   for(i=0;i<V;i++){
        visited[i]=0;

    DFS(0);
   }
   for(i=0;i<V;i++){
        if(visited[i]==0){
            component++;
        }
   }
   printf("\nNumber of components is: %d",component);

}

void DFS(int i)
{
    int j;
    printf("\n%d",i);
    visited[i]=1;

    for(j=0;j<V;j++)
       if(!visited[j]&&G[i][j]==1)
            DFS(j);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you invoke `DFS(0)` in the wrong place.  Surely it should be called between the loop that initializes `visited` and the loop that counts the number of visited components.  If there are 10 vertices, you call `DFS(0)` 10 times, but on the first call, only one element of the `visited` array is initialized, so you have undefined behaviour.  What else you need to do I'm not sure, but I'm pretty confident you need to fix that before going any further.  You may need an outer loop to start at each vertex (`for (int s = 0; s < V; s++) { …existing code…but call DFS(s);… }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the input, I edited the code and it seems to be passing the test cases but still not sure how to find the parent of each vertex.. The hint given in the question is as such: The parent of each vertex (a vertex p is the parent of vertex c if c is visited from p)